# PPL delphi. Определение статуса задачи

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Решил попробовать перевести потоки на [Parallel Programming Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library). Создаю задачу, в бесконечном цикле проверяю статус, и если он Canceled, то выполняю запись в лог и выхожу. Но почему то выход работает, а запись в лог нет.

```
while true do 
begin
 if TTask.CurrentTask.Status = TTaskStatus.Canceled then
 begin
   //очищение объектов
   //запись в лог
   exit;
 end;

 //основная работа

end;
```

Основная работа выполняется.
Завершение задачи

```
if Task.Status = TTaskStatus.Running then
Task.Cancel;
```

Запись в лог

```
function WriteLog(atype: integer; FileName : string; WriteText : string): boolean;
var
   f : Textfile;
   fName: string;
   FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
 try
   WriteText:=WriteText+#13#10;
   try
     if atype<>5 then CSectionWrFile.Enter;

      if atype=0 then
      begin
        result:=true;
      end
      else
      begin
       Result := False;

       if fl=cnt_log_f then
       begin
         fl:=0;
         rewr:=true;
       end;


       fName:=FileName+'_'+IntToStr(fl)+'.txt';



         if (FileExists(FName) = False)  then
         begin
            try
              FileStream := nil;
              try
                FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Fname,fmCreate);
                FileStream.Position := FileStream.Size;
                FileStream.Write(AnsiString(WriteText)[1],Length(WriteText));

              finally
                FileStream.Free;
              end;
            except
            end;
         end
         else
         begin
            try
              try
                FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Fname,fmOpenReadWrite+fmShareDenyNone);

                if FileStream.Size>=size_log_f then
                begin  //создаем новый файл и записываем в него строку
                  FileStream.Free;
                  inc(fl);
                  fName:=FileName+'_'+IntToStr(fl)+'.txt';

                  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Fname,fmCreate);
                  FileStream.Position := FileStream.Size;
                  FileStream.Write(AnsiString(WriteText)[1],Length(WriteText));
                end
                else
                begin
                  FileStream.Position := FileStream.Size;
                  FileStream.Write(AnsiString(WriteText)[1],Length(WriteText));
                end;

              finally
                FileStream.Free;
              end;
            except
            end;
         end;

         Result := True;

      end;

   finally
      if atype<>5 then  CSectionWrFile.Leave;
   end;
except

 end;

end;
```

Comment: Ну так покажите нам свою запись в лог :)

Comment: "Завершение задачи if Task.Status = TTaskStatus.Running then Task.Cancel;" - так все-таки cancel и лог в одном begin/end или в разных ветках?

Comment: В разных ветках

Comment: Может стоит убрать `except end;` и тогда станет понятно почему не работает лог? Ну или хотя бы что-то сделать в except?